# how to display identical values in a single column using EXCEL or ORACLE

Tags: oracle, excel, excel-formula, vba

Hello I need a formula in column ‘C’ which calculates/adds the amount of B Column based on the column A ID. If there are several amounts in same ID it should add the total amount and would show the result in column ‘C’ as a single row.

[image: image of sample data]

the output can be obtained from Oracle SQL query or an Excel formula.your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the same output from Oracle itself, using analytical functions like below.

`SUM() OVER(PARTITION BY ... )` -> This actually do the cumulative sum

```
WITH MYTABLE(ID,AMT) AS
  (SELECT '2UF2', '500' FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2TC6', '300' FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2TC6', '200' FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT '2TC6', '800' FROM DUAL
  )
SELECT ID,
  AMT,
  CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY NULL)
    WHEN 1
    THEN SUM(AMT) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY NULL)
  END AS FORMULA
FROM MYTABLE
ORDER BY ID, FORMULA NULLS LAST;
```

> [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/3054)

Answer (score 1):

You can use rollup in oracle

Select id,amt,sum (amt)  nullFrom table nullGroup by rollup (id,amt)

For more details see below link

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets

Comment: Roll up adds a separate row!

Comment: for excel follow this link http://superuser.com/questions/405555/how-can-i-group-by-and-sum-a-column-in-excel

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you need an aggregation function, in this case *sum*, and a *group by* clause. The generic query should look like the following:

```
Select sum(b) from table group by a
```

I hope this helps.